# How can I get the Scenario Outline Example iteration number

Tags: c#, specflow, scenarios

I have the following test, using Specflow, Selenium WebDriver and C#:

```
Scenario Outline: Verify query result
    Given I'm logged in
    When I enter "<query>"
    Then I should see the correct result

    Examples: 
    | query  |
    | Query1 |
    | Query2 |
    | Query3 |
```

After each scenario I save a screenshot to a file which is named based on the ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Title.
However, I can't find a good way to differentiate between the iterations, so the screenshots get overwritten. I could add a column in the Examples table, but I want a more generic solution...

Is there a way to know which iteration is being executed?

Comment: This is missing a lot of information about your question. Are you in a SQL statement? C#?

Answer (score 2):

In your When step definition you could record the current query in ScenarioContext.Current e.g.

```
[When(@"I enter (.*)")]
public void WhenIEnter(string query)
{
 ScenarioContext.Current["query"] = query;
}
```

Then in your AfterScenario step you could retrieve this value to identify which Example iteration just run e.g.

```
[AfterScenario]
void SaveScreenShot()
{
 var queryJustRun = ScenarioContext.Current["query"];

 // You could subsequently append queryJustRun to the screenshot filename to 
 // differentiate between the iterations
 // 
 // e.g. var screenShotFileName = String.Format("{0}_{1}.jpg",
 //                                ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Title,
 //                                queryJustRun ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible from what I can tell;
for a clearer example;

```
Scenario Outline: Add two numbers
    Given I have entered <first> into the calculator
    And I have entered <last> into the calculator
    When I press add
    Then the result should be <result> on the screen
Examples: 
| name   | first | last | result |
| simple | 1     | 1    | 2      |
| zero   | 0     | 0    | 0      |
```

if you look at the generated code then the `<name>` is not saved anywhere, it does not appear on either ScenarioContext or FeatureContext

TestExecutionResults in the report generator does seem to have this information, Model.TestExecutionResults[].TestItemResult.TestNode.Description is a composite string that includes the `<name>` element in there; but how it gets there is a mystery to me.

This is checked in the spec runner generated code and report generator

Answer (score 0):

The **name** will not appear unless you have defined in your scenario, which I can see you have not. Your feature could be written like this

```
  Scenario Outline: Performing mathematical operation
    Given I am on <name> scenario
    And I have entered <first> into the calculator
    And I have entered <last> into the calculator
    When I do the <operation> 
    Then the result should be <result> on the screen
Examples: 
| name   | first | last | result | operation |
| simple | 1     | 1    | 2      | add       |
| subs   | 6     | 2    | 4      | substract |
```

The advantage of structuring a above is that you can leverage on same scenario to perform several operations like 'add', 'subtract', 'multiply', etc